# Web Audio API - difference between PeriodicWave and looping AudioBufferSourceNode to achieve a wavetable?

Tags: javascript, fft, web-audio-api

I'm using two techniques to create a wavetable synthesizer sound :

1 - Loop an [AudioBufferSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode) which contains a single waveform cycle

```
// Load a single cycle short wave file, then :
  audioContext.decodeAudioData(audioData, function(buffer) {
     source.buffer = buffer;
     source.loop = true;
   },
```

2 - Create a [PeriodicWave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PeriodicWave) and provide it with fourier coefficients
   ( using coefficients found on the web, i.e. (0,1) for a sine wave,  (0,.1,.4, .6, ...) for more complex waves.

```
 var wave = ac.createPeriodicWave(real, imag); 
 OscillatorNode.setPeriodicWave(wave);
```

What are the pros and cons of using one technique over the other ?  Do these techniquees yield very different audible results ?

I have a demo here which plays both approaches : 
http://davedave.us/wavetable-synth/

My code is work in progress, but it's here : 
https://github.com/looshi/wavetable-synth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sample rate of the audio file you're loading and the sample rate of the audio context are the same, then there isn't really much difference between the two.  The main difference I can think of is that the buffer approach can produce glitches if the first and last samples of the loop differ significantly.  This won't happen with the periodic wave unless you make it that way.

If you don't change the frequency, the audio buffer might require somewhat less CPU to produce the audio.

For high fundamental frequencies, the periodic wave will probably sound a bit different because it is forced to be band-limited.  An audio buffer doesn't have that restriction.

Comment: Thanks!  The audio file loaded will be same sample rate as the audio context.  Also the buffer last sample will equal first sample by convention in the audio files.   I'll read up on what you mean by the periodic wave is forced to be band-limited, do you have more information or links which describe that in more detail?

Comment: See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandlimiting.  Basically, if you have a PeriodicWave for, say, a square wave, the harmonics mathemetically go to infinity. But WebAudio limits the highest harmonic to be less than half the sample rate, therefore limiting the bandwidth of the signal.  You can hear this be creating a square-wave oscillator.  Then increase the frequency of the oscillator.  Eventually, the output sounds like a sine wave instead of a square wave.  That's band-limiting---the higher harmonics are removed.

Answer (score 1):

An AudioBuffer is band limited because there's a non-zero amount of time between each sample, so it's not possible to create an idealized square wave with infinite bandwidth and dead vertical lines by writing to an AudioBuffer. In the simple case where the sample rate of the AudioBuffer equals the sample rate of the AudioContext then so long as the playbackRate is <=1 then the bandwidth required for the AudioBufferSource node will not exceed the maximum bandwidth of the AudioContext. But in any case the bandwidth required always has a known upper limit. If the playbackRate is >1 then depending on the contents of the buffer the bandwidth required might exceed the Nyquist frequency of the AudioContext (0.5 * sampleRate) and aliasing will occur.

However, if the pitch is altered by slowing down a sample rather than speeding it up then you'll lose detail in the bass notes. For example, if your sample rate is 44.1KHz and you use a playbackRate of 1 is to make the sound you want for A4 (440Hz) then your sample can contain information up to the 50th harmonic (22050 / 440). However, when you play the same sample with a playbackRate of 0.5 then the same information used to make the 50th harmonic of A4 is also used to create the 25th harmonic for A3 and your 26th and higher harmonics become silent. This quickly impacts on your ability to create fizzy bass sounds. You'll also introduce a subharmonic because the 1st harmonic of A4 becomes the 1/2 "harmonic" of A3. One solution is to use multiple samples for the same sound, for example to create a different sample for each octave. With one sample per octave then losing nearly half your harmonics is the worst it can get.

With the PeriodicWave, if your arrays contain data for the 51st harmonic then that information will be ignored when the frequency of the OscillatorNode is set to 440Hz, since only frequencies up to the 50th harmonic fit underneath the Nyquist frequency. However, when you lower the oscillator's frequency then higher harmonics will be included. However, if you only specify amplitudes up to the 50th harmonic then with a frequency of 220Hz you still only get 50 harmonics even though you could now fit 100 harmonics without going over the Nyquist frequency. Thus, if you wanted to recreate one of the built-in waveforms then you would need to specify 801 harmonics to fully synthesize A0 (22050 / 27.5), although some of them could be omitted because they'd fall outside the range of your hearing or the capabilities of your speakers. Recreating a triangle wave using PeriodicWave is pointless, but if you wanted to explore modifications to one of the basic wave formulae like maybe a curve that falls by `1/n**1.5` instead of `1/n` or `1/n**2` then you'll either need to use large arrays (and increase memory usage) or accept having bass notes that sound like they've been filtered. Another limitation of PeriodicWave is that you can't specify how the levels of the harmonics change over time unless you mix multiple oscillators, each with their own PeriodicWave and envelope.

Consequently, I discovered that although PeriodicWave offers much promise in terms of ultimate tweakability, in practice to create harmonically rich textures that preserve a consistent timbre across the keyboard it's actually easier to mostly stick to the basic waveforms (or very simple PeriodicWave-s) and use techniques like layering, audio rate modulation, polarity inversion, filters and simple waveshapers (e.g. absolute value, distortion, Chebyshev) to create and control the higher harmonics, although this does often require some creativity, ingenuity and mathematical thinking to craft the precise wave shape or harmonic structure you have in mind out of the basic building blocks.